# Create a container with object specified dynamically in JAVA

Tags: java, object, dynamic, vector

I want to crate a container in JAVA that will have containers which (the latter) will hold entries of objects whose class will be dynamically defined.

I cannot find any way of how to do this.

Can anyone indicate me either an official way to do it (if there is such) or a generic way or an other approach if my is not correct?

To be more specific, I try to do something like:

```
Vector<Vector< of what? > > myVector;
```

The `of what?` should be dynamically assigned for each vector that belongs in the outer one.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `Vector<Vector<?>>`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ArrayList<Object> container = new ArrayList<>();

// Now you can add any type of object in the ArrayList (container)
```

like you can add `Integer`, `String`, or other custom objects.

The *limit* of this approach is that there's no control over the type of objects you're inserting in the collection.

But this can be easily handled by

```
ArrayList<? super T> container = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare

```
Vector<Vector<?>> myVector;
```

And do the corresponding cast when you access the inner vector.

You won't find a way to do it that satisfies the Java's type system. There is no annotation available to say that "this type depends on this other type or value".